# React - jss nested Sass-like styling is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have an application where I am using [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) v.3 as a UI framework. I have a `label` with `button` that has `display: none` as the default state, that I would like to show on hover over the parent element.

I have made a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7cs4u) here of the relevant parts. The jsx code looks like this:

```
 <div className={classes.volumeWrapper}>
    <VolumeUpIcon />
    <input
      accept="image/*"
      className={classes.fileInput}
      id="contained-button-file"
      multiple
      type="file"
    />
    <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        component="span"
        className={classes.fileButton}
      >
        <AddIcon />
      </Button>
    </label>
  </div>
```

And the styling for it is this:

```
  fileInput: {
    display: "none"
  },
  volumeWrapper: {
    "& label": {
      display: "none"
    },
    "& :hover": {
      "& label": {
        display: "block"
      }
    }
  }
```

Why is this not working, and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) or [MUI React](https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/react/introduction)? Or something else? Do you have a reference?

Comment: https://v3.material-ui.com/ is the framework, there is also a link to codesandbox in the question, where you can see that